# Excel: Multiple filter columns in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a spreadsheet that contains a large amount of data concerning error codes of products. The spreadsheet has columns for three error codes to be entered.

For example:

```
errorcode1  errorcode2 errorcode3
88          
100         88
101
88          115        
110         90         88
```

The way the pivot table is set up, I can only filter by one error code. If I wanted to know the total 88 codes I would filter for 88 in errorcode1 which would only have a result of 2 even though there's two more.

Ideally the goal is to be able to add the results of the filters. For example

```
errorcode1  errorcode2  errorcode3
88
100         88
88          115
110         90          88
```

How can I accomplish a running total of the error codes instead of being limited to one column?

Comment: Besides the line 3 with 101 missing I don't see any difference between the first example and the second. Would you please explain... Could you add a visual of your Pivot Table, that will help to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a separate table with some =countifs(). (Obviously in your workbook I would reference the cell containing the code.)

```
Error code    Count
88            =countifs(A2:C10,88)
100           =countifs(A2:C10,100)
101           =countifs(A2:C10,101)
```

The advantages here are that you can easily add new error codes and then copy them down.

See screenshot below:

[image: example of countifs]

If you want to know the amount of error codes by error code, just only reference the correct column:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the help, but that's not entirely what I'm looking for. I have the data in a pivot table and I can filter by them using the drop down section. I would like to filter multiple drop down sections and have them essentially 'add' together and show me all the results instead of just for one column

Comment: @MikeBrunner Ok...I'm not sure exactly what you want. Do you mean you want to be able to filter multiple columns on a pivot table? Or does OldUgly's answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

Pivot tables work best when your source data is "flat" - i.e. There is no pre-organization done.

Your data is partially organized.

I would recommend having your raw data look like the following ...

```
Err Index   ErrCode
1   1   88
1   2   
1   3   
2   1   100
2   2   88
2   3   
3   1   101
3   2   
3   3   
4   1   88
4   2   115
4   3   
5   1   110
5   2   90
5   3   88
```

Now you can generate a number of interesting pivot tables ...

How many times has each ErrCode occurred?

[image]

How many times do I have multiple ErrCodes reported?

[image]

... and so forth.

**Edit: Flattening the data**

Assuming you have a large amount of source data that is already organized in the fashion you describe, I would use a short piece of VBA to flatten the data.

Below is an example:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Flatten()
Dim SrcSht As Worksheet
Set SrcSht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim DestSht As Worksheet
Set DestSht = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim LastSrcRow As Long
LastSrcRow = SrcSht.Range("A" & SrcSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim LastSrcCol As Long
LastSrcCol = SrcSht.Cells(1, SrcSht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

DestSht.Cells(1, 1) = "Err"
DestSht.Cells(1, 2) = "Index"
DestSht.Cells(1, 3) = "ErrCode"

Dim SrcRow As Long, SrcCol As Long, DestRow As Long
DestRow = 1
For SrcRow = 2 To LastSrcRow
    For SrcCol = 1 To LastSrcCol
        DestRow = DestRow + 1
        DestSht.Cells(DestRow, 1) = SrcRow - 1
        DestSht.Cells(DestRow, 2) = SrcCol
        DestSht.Cells(DestRow, 3) = SrcSht.Cells(SrcRow, SrcCol).Value
    Next SrcCol
Next SrcRow

Set SrcSht = Nothing
Set DestSht = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the help. That seems interesting and could possibly work. How could i transpose my list how i have it above into an indexed list like the one you showed?

Comment: I would use VBA. I edited the solution to include what the VBA might look like.